# How to optimize ANN structure using GA

Tags: matlab, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I've created NN model by editing the codes from ANN toolbox. In my work i need to study the effect of changing various ANN topology on its performance. The purpose of this model is to train the network with operating data from a steam turbine. The data is normalized and then the target will be set according to the actual fault occurrence which tagged as "1" and during normal operation "0". For my next work, I'm trying to optimize the ANN topology by using GA.

```
% load data
load data.mat;


x = data;
t = target;

% Choose a Training Function
% For a list of all training functions type: help nntrain
% 'trainlm' is usually fastest.
% 'trainbr' takes longer but may be better for challenging problems.
% 'trainscg' uses less memory. NFTOOL falls back to this in low memory situations.
trainFcn = 'trainscg';  % Bayesian Regularization

% Create a Feedforward Network
hiddenLayerSize = 6;
net = feedforwardnet (hiddenLayerSize,trainFcn);

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
RandStream.setGlobalStream(RandStream('mt19937ar','seed',1)); % to make the weight constant
net.divideFcn = 'divideblock'; % Divide targets into three sets using blocks of indices
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

%TRAINING PARAMETERS
net.trainParam.show=50;  %# of ephocs in display
net.trainParam.lr=0.05;  %learning rate
net.trainParam.epochs=10000;  %max epochs
net.trainParam.goal=0.05^2;  %training goal
net.performFcn='mse';  %Name of a network performance function %type help nnperformance

% Setup of activation/transfer function
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig';
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'tansig';

% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,x,t);

% Test the Network
y = net(x);
e = gsubtract(t,y);
performance = perform(net,t,y)

% View the Network
%view(net)

plot(1:length(t), t, 1:length(y), y);
```

How to use GA to optimize which of the three training algorithm gives the best RMSE. For my work I also need to consider the number of neuron, the number of hidden layers, and activation function. I planned on using binary encoding to do this such as:

```
% Preliminary function decoding:
            function [algo, archit, activf1, activf2] = decoding(X)
            %
            % function that decodes a binary string into information
            % about the NN structure and training tralgorithm
            %
            %   [algo, archit, activf1 activf2] = decoding(X)
            %
            % "X" is a population of binary strings of size 10 (excluding 32param)
            % eg:[00,0000,00 00]
            %
            % algo  = for training algorithm trainscg, trainlm, trainbr
            %       
            % archit = hidden layer neurons from 0000 to 1001 
            %
            % activf1 = type of activation functions of hidden nodes
            % activf2 = type of activation functions of output nodes
            %           = 00 for logsig
            %           = 01 for tansig
            %           = 10 for purelin
            %M=Pz (population size)
            M = size(X,1);
            %initializations:
            a = zeros(M,2); %size for algo (training algorithm)
            b = zeros(M,4); %size for archit (hidden layer neuron)
            c = zeros(M,4); %size for activf and activf2
            %d = zeros(Pz,32);
            for i=1:M
            a = X(i,1:2);
            b = X(i,3:8);
            c = X(i,9:10);
            % for algo (training algorithm)
            if (a == [0 0])
            algo(i) = ['trainscg'];
            elseif (a == [0 1])
            algo(i) = ['trainlm'];
            elseif (a == [1 0])
            algo(i) = ['trainbr'];
            end
            % for archit (hidden layer neuron)
            if (b == [0 0 0 0])
            archit(i,1) = 1;
            elseif (b == [0 0 0 1])
            archit(i,1) = 2;
            elseif (b == [0 0 1 0])
            archit(i,1) = 3;
            elseif (b == [0 0 1 1])
            archit(i,1) = 4;
            elseif (b == [0 1 0 0])
            archit(i,1) = 5;
            elseif (b == [0 1 0 1])
            archit(i,1) = 6;
            elseif (b == [0 1 1 0])
            archit(i,1) = 7;
            elseif (b == [0 1 1 1])
            archit(i,1) = 8;
            elseif (b == [1 0 0 0])
            archit(i,1) = 9;
            elseif (b == [1 0 0 1])
            archit(i,1) = 10;
            end
            % for activf and activf2
            if (c == [0 0 0 0])
            activf1(i,:) = ['logsig'];
            activf2(i,:) = ['logsig'];
            elseif (c == [0 0 0 1])
            activf1(i,:) = ['logsig'];
            activf2(i,:) = ['tansig'];
            elseif (c == [0 0 1 0])
            activf1(i,:) = ['logsig'];
            activf2(i,:) = ['purelin'];
            elseif (c == [0 0 1 1])
            activf1(i,:) = ['tansig'];
            activf2(i,:) = ['logsig'];
            elseif (c == [0 1 0 0])
            activf1(i,:) = ['tansig'];
            activf2(i,:) = ['tansig'];
            elseif (c == [0 1 0 1])
            activf1(i,:) = ['tansig'];
            activf2(i,:) = ['purelin'];
            elseif (c == [0 1 1 0])
            activf1(i,:) = ['purelin'];
            activf2(i,:) = ['logsig'];
            elseif (c == [0 1 1 1])
            activf1(i,:) = ['purelin'];
            activf2(i,:) = ['tansig'];
            elseif (c == [1 0 0 0])
            activf1(i,:) = ['purelin'];
            activf2(i,:) = ['purelin'];
            end
            end %for
            'Population was decoded!'
```

Based on my limited knowledge in GA, i need to create a fitness function and a function handle. The performance indicator of this network is RMSE so the RMSE should be the fitness for the GA. How to create the fitness function from here on forward? Please advise :)

Answer (score 0):

You can represent all connections in the ANN with graph neighbours matrix. If you have total of N neurons in the ANN you will have NxN neighbours matrix. This matrix can be the object of your GA optimization.

n(i) = 1 / (1 - exp(-sum(a(i,j)*w(i,j)*n(j)))